# SprinBoot app launched from IDE - SpelEvaluationException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a simple SpringBoot app with web security and method security config using a custom SecurityExpressionRoot.
When I **launch the SB app from an IDE** (e.g. STS or IDEA) and call an endpoint I get

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:
Method call: Method hasAnyAccess(java.lang.String) cannot be found on
org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot type
```

When I **launch the SB app from CLI** with the app jar file the endpoint call succeeds:

```
INFO 11282 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.e.CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot   :
< CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(): [org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@442a8f33: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@36ebcb: Username: user; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@166c8: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 36E17CAA657E897B1682BFF27EA7DA1F; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER]
INFO 11282 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.e.CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot   :
> hasAnyAccess(): [[FULL_ACCESS]]
```

ANY help is highly appreciated.

Web security configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
}
```

Method security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new CustomPermissionEvaluator());
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

Method security expression handler:

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {
    private AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation invocation) {
        CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot root = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication);
        root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
        root.setTrustResolver(this.trustResolver);
        root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());
        return root;
    }
}
```

Security expression root:

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {

    public CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication) {
        super(authentication);
        LOGGER.info("< CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(): [{}]", authentication);
    }

    public final boolean hasAnyAccess(String... accessLevels) {
        LOGGER.info("> hasAnyAccess(): [{}]", Arrays.asList(accessLevels));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER') && hasAnyAccess('FULL_ACCESS')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(@RequestParam String name) {
        return "Hello '" + name + "' at " + System.currentTimeMillis() + "\n";
    }
}
```

**Update 1:**
The same SpelEvaluationException happens when the SB app is launched with

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

**Update 2:**
From the logs it seem **when launching from IDE my MethodSecurityConfig extension is overridden by GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration**:

```
INFO 5927 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : 
Overriding bean definition for bean 'methodSecurityInterceptor' with a different definition:
replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=methodSecurityConfig; factoryMethodName=methodSecurityInterceptor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred);
defined in class path resource [com/example/MethodSecurityConfig.class]]
with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration; factoryMethodName=methodSecurityInterceptor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred);
defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]]

INFO 5927 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : 
Overriding bean definition for bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' with a different definition:
replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=methodSecurityConfig; factoryMethodName=methodSecurityMetadataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred);
defined in class path resource [com/example/MethodSecurityConfig.class]]
with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration; factoryMethodName=methodSecurityMetadataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred);
defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]]
```

When launching from JAR **my MethodSecurityConfig extension overrides the GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration**:

```
INFO 6092 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : 
Overriding bean definition for bean 'methodSecurityInterceptor' with a different definition:
replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration; factoryMethodName=methodSecurityInterceptor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred);
defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]]
with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=methodSecurityConfig; factoryMethodName=methodSecurityInterceptor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred);
defined in class path resource [com/example/MethodSecurityConfig.class]]

INFO 6092 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : 
Overriding bean definition for bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' with a different definition:
replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration; factoryMethodName=methodSecurityMetadataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred);
defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]]
with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=methodSecurityConfig; factoryMethodName=methodSecurityMetadataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred);
defined in class path resource [com/example/MethodSecurityConfig.class]]
```

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation it turned out the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` annotation specified for both

- `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` extension and
- `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` extension

causes the problem. Removing the annotation from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` solves the issue.